# How to convert each character of a string into individual elements of list element in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert a given string's individual characters into individual elements of a list in Python?

```
b = []
a = "golf"
for i in a:
    print(i)
    b.append(i)
```

I expect an output as:

```
b = ['g','o','l','f']
```

but the actual output is

```
g
o
l
f
```

Comment: Try printing `b`

Comment: Simply `b = list(a)`

Comment: Although your approach may be an overkill it is still very fine and correct. Your only problem is the way you present it. You are printing each letter with a `print` statement which prints on separate lines. Your result is held in `b` so simply add `print(b)` after the loop

Comment: `b = ['g', 'o', 'l', 'f']` isn't output; it's a definition. This loop produces the desired value of `b` whether or not you call `print` on each individual character.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = "golf"
b = list(a)
print (b)
```

simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect an output as:
>
> b = ['g','o','l','f']

That's what you'd get if you tried (after the loop):

```
print("b = {}".format(b))
```

but since there's no such thing in your code, there's no reason it should be printed...

> but the actual output is
>
> g
>
> o
>
> l
>
> f

Well yes, that's what you asked for:

```
# ...
for i in a:
    print(i) # <- HERE
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
b = []
a = "golf"
for i in a:
    b.append(i)
b
```

The expected output will be:

```
['g','o','l','f']
```

Or:

```
b = []
a = "golf"
for i in a:
    b.append(i)
print("b = {}".format(b))
```

and you will get this output:

```
b = ['g','o','l','f']
```